# Scala convert JSON to one of a number of types

Tags: json, scala

I am receiving some JSON from a stream.

The object could be represented by one of a number of scala types.  For example: `{"userid":"blerk","name":"Fred"}` would be `User(userId:String, userName:String)`

`{"groupId":"zerk","name":"Accounting"}` would be `Group(groupId:String,groupName:String}`

(real-life objects have many more elements).

I'm using spray-json if that matters, but what I want to know is this:

I'd like to have a function "convert" that sequentially does a `Try(myJson.convertTo[T])` until it is successful, and returns a value of type `T`.

My objective is to avoid using some kind of string-matching heuristics to figure out in advance what type it may be, and just be able to append a new Type to a list when a new case comes up.  I would also like to avoid code like

```
val t1=Try(myJson.convertTo[User])
if(t1.isSuccess) return t1.get
val t2=Try(myJson.convertTo[Group])
if(t2.isSuccess) return t2.get
```

Sadly, I'm having trouble wrapping my little brain around this and would be grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Try`'s [`orElse` method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.util.Try@orElse[U>:T](default:=>scala.util.Try[U]):scala.util.Try[U]) to do what you're asking for. Here's a first attempt:

```
import scala.util.Try
import spray.json._, DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class User(userId: String, userName: String)
case class Group(groupId: String, groupName: String)

implicit val userFormat: JsonFormat[User] = jsonFormat2(User)
implicit val groupFormat: JsonFormat[Group] = jsonFormat2(Group)

val groupJson = """{ "groupId": "zerk", "groupName": "Accounting" }""".parseJson
val userJson = """{ "userId": "foo", "userName": "Foo McBar" }""".parseJson

val result = Try(groupJson.convertTo[User]).orElse(Try(groupJson.convertTo[Group]))
```

If you have more than two types to try, you can put the attempts in a sequence and fold over them with `_ orElse _`.

This will work, but it gives you a result of type `Try[Any]`, which is pretty much useless if you care about type safety, although you could always pattern match on the result if you're willing to deal with the fact that in principle you could have anything there.

A better approach is to decode into an `Either`:

```
scala> groupJson.convertTo[Either[Group, User]]
res3: Either[Group,User] = Left(Group(zerk,Accounting))

scala> userJson.convertTo[Either[Group, User]]
res4: Either[Group,User] = Right(User(foo,Foo McBar))
```

This also generalizes to more than two types, although you have to nest `Either`s:

```
scala> userJson.convertTo[Either[Either[Group, String], User]]
res5: Either[Either[Group,String],User] = Right(User(foo,Foo McBar))
```

If you want a cleaner way of working with a result that can be end up as one of more than two types, [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless)'s `Coproduct` is a nice principled solution. You'll need to write your own format for coproducts, but it's a relatively straightforward exercise.

That's going the extreme type-safety route, though. If you don't care just use `orElse`.

Comment: Thank you; since this is a learning exercise, I'm not willing to give up on type-safety (at least not yet). And since there are quite a few possible types, the nested `Either` route isn't completely satisfactory either ;-).  I appreciate the link to Shapeless since their `ShapelessStream` looks like it may be useful as well!